# I am worried about SQL Injections. Is this safe?

Tags: php, mysql

I am starting a very basic site that uses a single line form to post into a database and then later echo that `$comment` variable on the page. I don't know PDO, but am willing to learn if I truly need it for something this simple.

```
else
mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (postid, post_content)
VALUES ('', '$comment <br />')");
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Above this code I have basic strpos commands to block out some of the things I don't want posted.

Am I going to experience any issues with injections down the road from how I am doing this?

Comment: start learning prepared statements using `PDO` while you're at it

Comment: PDO can look intimidating at the start. But doing basic queries is pretty much the same amount of code ad mysqli. Plus once you need/want the more advanced features, that is where it shines over mysqli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not safe, you need to use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape `$comment`.

But, PDO is nothing difficult and make your code stronger.

```
// create the connection. something like mysql_connect/mysql_error
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// create the prepared statement.
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (postid, post_content) VALUES (?, ?)");
// execute it with parameters.
$stmt->execute(array('', $comment.'<br>'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is dangerous.  All someone has to do is put a single quote then the SQL code they want after.  Use $comment = [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)($comment) before this statement if you want to fix it the old way or use PDO prepared statements as the newer way. Here is a basic example from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: I have seen this and read up on it before. What exactly does the mysql_real_escape_string(); do?

Comment: There are certain characters (like single quote for one) which need to be escaped so it will turn all ' into \' or '' depending on the version of escaping used. [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is susceptible to sql injection as your $comment is input from the user they may as well enter some SQL command and your PHP code will end up executing the same.

Consider $comment value is set to `'TRUNCATE TABLE USERS;'` the USERS table could be anything which might be critical for your app.

In PHP I believe you safeguard against sql injection by using `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Read up on it.

Refer this doc for details abt SQL innjection: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rO_LCBKJY0puvRhPhAfTD2iNVPfR4e9KiKDpDE2enMI/edit?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

Binding form input data to mysql query is the perfect solution to the sql injection. Use binaParam method for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

No, judging only by the code you’ve posted here, you are not protected against SQL injections. Here’s a simple example for `$comment`:

```
'), (null, (select concat(user(),':',password) s from mysql.user where concat(user,'@',host)=user() LIMIT 1) --
```

This will add another row containing the login credentials of the current user. With `LOAD_FILE` he could also be able to read files from your file system. He could also write arbitrary files on the file system:

```
' + (select '<?php echo "Hello, World!";' into dumpfile '/path/to/your/document_root/foobar.php')) --
```

With this technique the attacker could upload arbitrary files to your server, e. g. a web shell to run arbitrary commands on your system.

So you definitely must [protect yourself against SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) whereby automatic escaping using prepared statements or parameterized statements is favored over manual escaping using functions like `mysql_real_escape_string`.